# retrieving the value of a field from another model in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

please I would like to know how I can get the value of a field from another model in Odoo 12. I have a contact class and another class where I want to get the phone number of the contact class and when I use the many2one relationship it brings me the email addresses and not the phone number. I specify any time that I inherited the contact class from Odoo and I added the telephone field in this class

Comment: How did you try to get the vaue using many2one field.

Comment: here is the relationship that i use :  recipient= fields.Many2one(comodel_name= "mail.mass_mailing.contact", required = True)

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: Thank you very much I managed to recover the phone number. I called the Odoo mailing list class with a Many2many and I sent messages from this list by retrieving the numbers but I got an error which is as follows: File "c: \ program files (x86) \ odoo 12.0 \ server \ addons \ KeoMarketing \ models \ messages_sms.py ", line 36, in send_sms
     '& sms =' + self.messages_sms
TypeError: must be str, not mail.mass_mailing.list

Comment: I think my loop in the mailing list does not read the phone numbers but rather the contact ids

Comment: I think this is another question, feel free to accept my answer bellow if it worked for you. I will check your other question at [TypeError: must be str, not mail.mass_mailing.list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954847/typeerror-must-be-str-not-mail-mass-mailing-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `emails` because `_rec_name` is set to the `email` field. note that emails are just displayed names, the `recipient` field is a reference to a `mail.mass_mailing.contact` record.

To get a phone number instead of an email you can:

- Override `name_get` to display `phone_number`:

  ```
  def name_get(self):
      res_list = []
      for contact in self:
          res_list.append((contact.id, contact.phone_number))
      return res_list
  ```

  You can check if `phone_number` is empty and display another value instead.
- Add a related field `phone_number` next to `recipient` field:

  ```
  recipient= fields.Many2one(comodel_name= "mail.mass_mailing.contact", required = True)
  phone_number = fields.Char(related='recipient.phone_number')
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Get value from another field in xml file in odoo :

```
<page string="Properties">
   <field name="property_ids" context="{'id':active_id}">
   <!-- key can be any, property type active id -->
       <tree>
           <field name="name" />
           <field name="price" />
           <field name="property_status" />
       </tree>
   </field>
</page>
```

For ex : if current model is property type, i want fields of real_Estate properties (which is another model), add this type of code to current model (here, property_type)

Here from code, property_ids field is available in property_type model, only then it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).