# TypeError: must be str, not mail.mass_mailing.list

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am making a module on Odoo to send sms from a mailing list.
I have run this code but I have an error.

```
contact_list_ids = fields.Many2many('mail.mass_mailing.list', 'phone_number', string='Liste de diffusion')

messages_sms = fields.Text(string="message", required=True)

# send SMS with GET method
@api.multi
def send_sms(self):
    for list in self.contact_list_ids:
        for contact in list:
            final_url = (
                URL +
                '&to=' +contact +
                '&sms=' + self.messages_sms
                 )
            r = requests.get(final_url)
            if not r:
                return ERROR_API
            return r.text
```

The error:

> File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\addons\KeoMarketing\models\messages_sms.py", line 36, in send_sms
>       '&sms=' + self.messages_sms
>   TypeError: must be str, not mail.mass_mailing.list

Comment: In which line r u getting this error?

Comment: at this line: '&sms=' + self.messages_sms

Comment: The error says that self.message_sms is a list and not a single str value. try ```print(type(self.messages_sms))``` to see if this is true. Make sure that self.messages_sms is a str and not a list...

Comment: Yes. i think what is causing the error is my many2many fields

Answer (score 0):

You got a type error because you can't concatenate str with a `mail.mass_mailing.list` record.

```
'&to=' + contact
```

Try to pass the phone number instead (or any field used to store the phone number):

```
'&to=' + contact.phone_number
```

You can check the following `Twilio` example:

```
from twilio.rest import Client


class CustomClass(models.Model):   

    contact_list_ids = fields.Many2many('mail.mass_mailing.list', 'phone_number', string='Liste de diffusion')

    messages_sms = fields.Text(string="message", required=True)

    @api.multi
    def send_sms(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        account_sid = ''
        auth_token = ''
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
        for list in self.contact_list_ids:
            for contact in list.contact_ids:
                client.messages \
                    .create(
                    body=self.messages_sms,
                    from_=self.env.user.partner_id.mobile,
                    status_callback='http://postb.in/1234abcd',
                    to=contact.phone_number
                )


class MailMassMailingContact(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mail.mass_mailing.contact'

    phone_number = fields.Char()
```

- *The phone number used to send SMS is stored in the related partner of the current user*
- *I inherited `mail.mass_mailing.contact` to add a phone number for each contact*